# How to add namespace to TF2?

Tags: ros2, tf2, static-transform-publisher

When launching nodes which use TF2, the namespace doesn't appear to show up under the TF2 messages meaning you can't differentiate between robots/sensors.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

What you refer as namespace in TF2 is actually called a [prefix](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/99760/what-is-the-naming-conventions-for-tf-prefix-vs-ns).
It is used to make sure all links on a given TF tree have a specific name, even in a multi-robot configuration.

There is no link with the concept of namespace, that is used to identify the nodes, topics and services.

As shown in the link above and on [this one](https://answers.ros.org/question/405822/multi-robot-tf-with-namespaces-for-tf-or-with-frame_prefix-what-is-the-right-way-to-do-it-ros2/), you have two ways to resolve this:

- by using `xacro` to rename your links on the fly
- by using a separate `/tf` topic for each robot

Comment: I think the basic issue is you normally have namespaces to differentiate nodes running between two different robots and naturally you want to extend that to TF2. How would using a separate /tf topic work?

Comment: Well if each robot has their own /tf topic there is no need to differentiate the links themselves. They are not part of the same tree (e.g. tf topic) anyway.
This is done in the navigation stack multi-robot example in order to let each nav2 node use the same frame names (base_link, odom, scan...) without having to worry about the namespace they run in.

Comment: I'm asking how do you give each robot its own tf topic? Is there an example I can use to understand? I tried namespaces and it didn't seem to impact tf topics in any way.